# Twitter request token OAuth 401 error

Tags: twitter, oauth

Trying to add twitter login using OAuth and it has been a nightmare to get the first step of requesting the token, which results in 401 error as always.

I used twitter's Test OAuth tool to compare the http request that my scala server sends.
**Curl** request **works** while my **server** request **fails**. Pasting them below for comparison.
**Curl Request**

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token' --data 'oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8081%2Fweb' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="wRflKWWomJ9jKeK8wbTk0Jck3", oauth_nonce="46ef029600fcc2a6cbe068eb9711401c", oauth_signature="3ptB%2B6%2Fv9QYGgyQjO9DhuD7pmzA%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1422879905", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

**Scala server Request**

```
HttpRequest(POST,https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,List(Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="wRflKWWomJ9jKeK8wbTk0Jck3", oauth_nonce="70449464359328", oauth_signature="yEni23tuzEveIMtDm7%2F8N2anU%2FM%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1422879900", oauth_version="1.0"),HttpEntity(application/x-www-form-urlencoded,oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8081%2Fweb),HTTP/1.1)
```

**Things I tried:**

- Made sure timestamp is within 5 minutes
- Made sure "**Allow this
  application to be used to Sign in with Twitter**" is set in twitter
  settings.
- Callback url is set - http://0.0.0.0:8081/web (even tried
  proxy names for localhost by changing ip table)
- Tried generating request token using [Saclaj](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http)
- Used custom OAuth signature request primarily using [OAuth.scala](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-spray-twitter/blob/master/src/main/scala/core/OAuth.scala)

This 401 twitter request token seems to be a recurring theme for many folks, complicated by various failure points. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else facing this issue, I am listing down few things that you could benefit from.

> After excruciating attempts of permutations and combinations,
>   `oauth_token` had to be a part of the signature (even if its value is
>   empty string). 
> I am not sure if it is mentioned anywhere and particularly ironic that you had to remove access token and secret while using Twitter's OAuth testing tool (for the Curl command to work properly which took some bloody lot of time to figure out.)

- It is good to validate your basestring - [Tool](http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/)
- Validating if your signature process is correct - [Check point (f)](https://twittercommunity.com/t/solved-java-oauth-request-token-flow-example-without-libraries/1440)

Answer (score 0):

#### Another possible scenario

In my Twitter client app settings screen, I set an option *"Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)"* and this caused me getting 401 unauthorized error on trying to get request token.