# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized for oAuth token request in Twitter

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller

**Error Details**

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Am I missing anything?

I have already checked this url: [Twitter request token OAuth 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278162/twitter-request-token-oauth-401-error)

but did not help

**Get Token**

```
public void getRequestToken()
{
    oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()).Substring(0, 16).ToString();
    oauth_timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
    oauth_signature = create_auth_Signature_Task();

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_twitterConfig.request_token_url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    var auth = "OAuth oauth_callback=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("Callback url");
    auth += ",oauth_consumer_key=client id";
    auth += ",oauth_nonce=nonce val";
    auth += ",oauth_signature=signature";
    auth += ",oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
    auth += ",oauth_timestamp=timestamp";
    auth += ",oauth_version=1.0";

    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("Expect", "");
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, auth);

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

**Signature Creation**

```
private string create_auth_Signature_Task()
{
    var finalStr = "oauth_callback=my url";
    finalStr += "&oauth_consumer_key=key";
    finalStr += "&oauth_nonce=nonce val";
    finalStr += "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
    finalStr += "&oauth_timestamp=oauth_timestamp";
    finalStr += "&oauth_version=1.0";

    finalStr = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(finalStr);

    var signatureBaseString = "POST&" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_twitterConfig.request_token_url) + "&" + finalStr;
    var signatureKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_twitterConfig.consumer_secret);

    return ShaHash(signatureBaseString, signatureKey);
}

private string ShaHash(string value, string key)
{
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(key)))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)));
    }
}
```

Comment: The posting is 7 year old.  Things have changed.  If TLS is 1.3 than "HMAC-SHA1" won't work("HMAC-SHA1").  Is URL HTTP or HTTPS?  You would get 401 if you are using HTTP and server wants HTTPS.   You would also get if oauth failed.

Comment: TLS is working.  TLS is sent before the request is sent and you would not send request if TLS fails.  Also means you would not get the 401 response.  Local host may be set wrong so check with cmd.exe >ping localhost.  Should return back with 127.0.0.1 (loopback) or the IP/Name of machine.  Which means the oauth is failing.  I  would try changing the Encode from ASCII to UTF8.  ASCII will filter non printable characters.  What are you using for server?  Maybe the key/certificate is different on server.

Comment: Something is different in server than client.  See if Event Viewer is showing any error, What server app are you using?  Can you debug server code?